# Ethernaut challenge -Lv22 Dex - allowance approval problem

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I'm trying to complete the Dex level of ethernaut challenge which is quite easy.
In order to use swap I need firstly to approve token allowance, but I don't understand why when I call the approve function metamask get stucked without giving me any possibility of signing the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something with metamask trying to display two ERC20 token approval messages
Try approving your token amount separately for each token

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by creating a file in Remix with just *Import=https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"* and then load the contract addresses using the "At Address" input under the deploy section. You can then approve the tokens with your contract instance using the approve function in Remix. Please take a look at this video if you need more help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZLgOUCmgb8&ab_channel=SuperJackdrummer